# Zend Framework calling _partial from a model class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I can call partial method from a view object. However, I need to call it from a model class (which is standalone). I need to render a xhtml piece (with code) and parse the result and it happens inside a model class.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you say why you need to do this? Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, but usually views shouldn't be generated by the models directly. Any interaction with the views should be done by the controllers.

Here's a code snippet to use Zend_View as a standalone:

```
    $view = new Zend_View;
    $view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/blog/views/');

    $view->subject = $subject;

    $htmlMessage = $view->render('emails/template.phtml');
```

Comment: On my particular case i need to define setScriptPath instead of setBasePath

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access your view object, and subsequently partial view helper, in a model as follows:

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');
$view->partial(/*usual parameters here*/);
```